# If $^{t\mkern-5mu}A A = I_k$ in which way should I think about : $A\, ^{t\mkern-5mu}A$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, intuition

> Let $A \in M_{n,k}(\mathbb{R})$ such that : $^{t\mkern-5mu}AA = I_k$ then what can be said about : $A\, ^{t\mkern-5mu}A$ ? In which way should I think about the transformation $A^tA$ ?

First of when $n = k$ it's easy since $A$ is orthogonal so $A$ is basically a rotation or a reflexion. Now it's more difficult when $n \ne k$.

The fact that : $^{t\mkern-5mu}A A =I_k$ means that $k > n$ since otherwise $A$ can't be surjective. So we can deal with the case $k > n$ only.
When $k > n$ it means that $A$ is surjective and $^{t\mkern-5mu}A$ is injective. So when looking at : $A\, ^{t\mkern-5mu}A$ we are basically taking a vector $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and return a vector $a \in \mathbb{R}^k$ such that $Aa = v$ and then apply $A$. So it should give us : $A\,^{t\mkern-5mu}A = I_n$ yet this is false... So here my intuition is flawed.

Thank you !

Comment: If $^{t\mkern-5mu}A A =I_k$, it is $^{t\mkern-5mu}A $ which is surjective and $A$ injective.

Comment: As $rank(A\cdot B) \leq min\{rank(A), rank(B)\}$, $k = rank(^tAA) \leq min \{k, n\}$, so in fact $k < n$, not the other way around.

Comment: @Bernard Yes thank you for noticing you are completely right.

Comment: @enedil Yes you are right, I messed up because I thought that $A$ was surjective whereas as Bernard said it's injective not surjective.

Comment: You know for instance that it's symmetric.